# PHP/jQuery - Highlight the menu with current page

Tags: php, jquery

Hi
I am going to highlight a menu item according to the page that is reading currently, when user click on different page through the menu, that menu item will be highlighted, example is http://templates.joomlart.com/ja_pyrite/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=44&Itemid=53.

If I use PHP/jQuery to check the url and highlight the menu, it will be good if the url look like "http://example.com/contact", but the example above is bad.

If I don't going to check the url and highlight the menu item, could someone give me a idea/method that can be done with the same effect?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like this

```
<div id="nav_menu">
<?php
    $currentFile = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $pages = array(
        array("file" => "/index.php", "title" => "Home"),
        array("file" => "/about.php", "title" => "About Us"),
        array("file" => "/schedule.php", "title" => "Schedule")
    );
    $menuOutput = "<ul>";
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
       $activeAppend = ($page["file"] == $currentFile) ? " id='active' " : "class='nav_button'";
       $currentAppend = ($page["file"] == $currentFile) ? " id='current' " : "class='nav_button'";
       $menuOutput .= "<li " . $currentAppend . ">"
                   .  "<a href='" . $page["file"] . "' id='".$page["id"]."'>" . $page["title"] ."</a>"
                   .  "</li>"; 
    }           
    $menuOutput .= "</ul>";

    echo $menuOutput;
?>
</div>
```

i hope you get the idea, i had this on stackoverflow a while ago but i forgot what was the question

edit:

here i finnally found the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546106/how-to-properly-build-a-navigation-menu-that-highlights-the-current-page)

Answer (score 5):

I found this on [960 Development](http://960development.com/code-snippet/apply-active-class-on-current-page-menu-item/), been googling for a while for this, so happy when I finally found it!

```
<ul class="sub-nav" >
<?php
    $full_name = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $name_array = explode('/',$full_name);
    $count = count($name_array);
    $page_name = $name_array[$count-1];
?>
<li><a class="<?php echo ($page_name=='where-to-buy.php')?'active':'';?>" href="where-to-buy.php">WHERE TO BUY</a></li>
<li><a class="<?php echo ($page_name=='about.php')?'active':'';?>" href="about.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a class="<?php echo ($page_name=='contact.php')?'active':'';?>" href="contact.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
```

It is working fully for me, get the pages I need to be "active" to be active and dosent active any of thoes who got the class when I'm in another page!

Take a look at it!

Edit:

Even if you got a (in this example) contact.php?person=John, it will "active" the contact.php link!

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML code you use to generate your navigation, add some PHP logic that will add a `selected` class to the button of the page that you are currently on.  Then just add some CSS for the `selected` class.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this? It should select any link that points at the current page - so you can apply whatever you like to highlight it.

```
$('a[href="'+window.location+'"]').addClass('menu-highlight');
```

Comment: so the idea to highlight the menu item should be checking url?

Comment: @Charles: sorry, I don't understand. What are you asking?

Comment: I don't know what is the function/meaning of your code. Is it checking the url to know which page is reading by user and give the specific menu item a css class?

Comment: @Charles: yes, that's the intention of my code. I think it's a better method than adding logic on the server side. But I have not tested this - you may need to url-encode or escape `window.location` so that the strings match.

Comment: thanks for the idea, but if I has many page, then the script of checking may very long. any idea for this situation?

Comment: @Charles: no, the script should look very much like what I have above - it just checks the 'window.location' property (which will by itself dynamically change the match the url of the current page).

Answer (score 0):

A good technique is to add a specific `class` or `id` attribute to `body` element and then style it in CSS. It requires minimum of server side programming and keeps all the presentation logic in CSS as it should be done.

```
<style>
.contact #contact { background:#000; }
...
</style>

<body class="contact">
    <ul>
        <li id="homepage">Homepage</li>
        ...
        <li id="contact">Contact</li>
    </ul>
 ...
```